# How to set the correct path for an ImageIcon?

Tags: java, path, imageicon

I really will appreciate some help here:

**My current scenario**: I've been facing an error each time I try to load: 
*jPanel*, *jFrame*, *jInternalFrame* or *any other java component (java.swing.**component**)* . If I load my panel with an ImageIcon set like this ones (*described below*) I get a nullpointerexeption because it's not found the image wiith the image's path provided in the String.

Note: My IDE is Oracle's JDeveloper 11G.

---

private ImageIcon image1 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(***path***));

format 1:

> **"..\\src\\Image\\add.png"** , **".\\src\\Image\\add.png"** ,**"\\src\\Image\\add.png"**

(I realized this:[**"..\\src\\Image\\add.png"**] works to almost everyone in my college, if I run any project that was not developed by myself it works fine otherwise it fails.)

format 2:

> **"..\\Image\\add.png"**, **".\\Image\\add.png"**, **"\\Image\\add.png"**

format 3:

> **"..\\add.png"**, **".\\add.png"**, **"\\add.png"**

format 4:

> **"../src/Image/add.png"** , **"./src/Image/add.png"** ,**"/src/Image/add.png"**

format 5:

> **"../Image/add.png"** , **"./Image/add.png"** ,**"/Image/add.png"**

format 6:

> **"../add.png"** , **"./add.png"** ,**"/add.png"**

---

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Instead of guessing, have you read the javadoc of Class.getResource()?

Comment: Hi, Sorry but Im a **kind of new** in programming, could you be kind to provide me the steps to review the details or any documentation online, I just found more questions in this site about "javadoc of Class.getResource()" Thanks.

Comment: @JB thank you... below you posted the link(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) If I've understood correctly the path in my case should be this one based in the oracle documentation: **"/src/Image/add.png"** Please let me know if I'm wrong otherswise I'll check it in the Jdeveloper to find out if this can make any difference.

Comment: I've confirmed the Image is in the right directory but unfortunately for me **"...getResource("/src/Image/add.png" ));"** is not working, it still generates a nullpointerexception in the ImageIcon object.

Comment: The path is constituted with the package name, where dots are replaces by slashes. If you had a class in src/Image, since src is just the directory where you store all your sources, its package name would be `Image`, right? So, the resource path must be `/Image/add.png`. You must understand that, when you execute your program, the src directory is completely irrelevant, and could even not exist at all. java uses the classpath to local classes and resources. Your IDE compiles the java source files to .class files stored in some directory (typically named bin or classes)

Comment: ... and also copies the resources there. This directory is one of the roots of the classpath, and te path is relative to that root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the correct path for the ImageIcon, thank you all for your comments. I really appreciate it.

**Short answer:**

*Based in the scenario I've previously described* the correct ***path*** in the Sting must be ***"/Image/add.png"*** or ***"/package_folder/file.png"***

The image files *must be placed* in ***App_Folder\Project\classes\package_name*** but also should show up in ***"App_Folder\Project\src\package_name"*** (the folders can be replaced if any new image is added)

Screenshots of
[AppFolder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVP09.jpg) and [Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAGHc.jpg) for better understanding

Summarizing in this scenario the code is:

> ***ImageIcon image1 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Image/add.png"));***

---

**per my understanding, this one is my humbly explanation**:

JDeveloper looks for the image file in the location of the packages and classes. 
This one is  App_Folder\Project\classes\package name. If we look closely the structure is looking for the resource in the class, this may be enough to "get it"
but if somebody else like me need more hints, there it goes.

I found my mistake was this one:
It seems that JDeveloper has two repositories instead of one or it's a kind of backup for the packages and the classes.
Since an abreviation for "source" can be src, I thought, If I'm placing the files in the package in the src (source) and the path based in the Javadocs that is "/Image_Package/ImageFile.(type)" is correct. Why am I facing this NullPointerException?

I checked the same details with my teacher in the college today and it worked, but back at home I faced the same error and I started to look in the other files to check the details about "class" and "resource" so I found out there's another folder that contains the same packages but this one was not "updated" (if we describe it like this) with the new images I placed in the src one. Then I pasted the new images, re-opened the Developer and I ran the script... Finally the Jframe emerged with the new icons.

I hope this details can help someone.

---

Answer (score 0):

ImageIcon is not your problem. The key is `getClass().getResource()` which loads a file from the same source as java also reads the class files.

In other words: if your classpath is `-cp .` or any other directory, `getResource()` will also load files from there, relative to the given directory ("." is the current directory)

If your classpath is a `.jar` file, the path is lookup up *inside* this jar and nowhere else.

Now to the path given your classpath is /a/bin and your class is `c.d.E`:

- `/` is the root. Not the root of the filesystem but the root of the classpath. In this example this is `/a/bin/`.
- `.` means the location of the class. In the example this is `/a/bin/c/d/`
- `..` means one step back, which is `/a/bin/c/`. This works because Java asks the filesystem for the path `/a/bin/c/d/../`.

If the path is a .jar file and your class is `c.d.E`:

- `/` is the root of the jar.
- `.` means the location of the class. In the example this is `c/d/` inside the jar
- `..` is not documented

If you use `\\` or `/` as separator doesn't matter on Windows. In all other cases you have to use `/`.

Now, I hope I didn't include a mistake...

Comment: You can't use . nor .. in a resource path. Either you start from the class package by using a/b/c, or you start from the root using /a/b/c.

Comment: Oh, and the separator MUST be /, whatever the platform is. That is documented.

Comment: Yes, it happens to work, by eccident, when the resource is loaded fromthe file system. Why would you ever use an undocumented feature that only works when the class is loaded from the file system (which, outside of development, practically never happens)? Code that works is not sufficient. Code that is correct is what matters.

Comment: But your answer says that it can be used. It shouldn't. I haven't downvoted yet, but I'm about to.

Comment: Well, I read the documentation https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29 over and over again and have to say it's hard to understand for a non-native english speaker. But it you look closely, it even mentions "." which you say isn't documented. But if you feel to downvote, do it. I would also like to see your own answer here with links to the corresponding docs

Comment: Thank you both for the details. I really appreciate it. Now I've the oracle Javadocs and I can check it

Comment: By the way I'm in college so I'm still learning about programming, honestly I'm not used to review the Javadocs as a basic procedure or first step, I'll do my best to keep in mind this in the next doubts I can face.

Comment: @DanielAlder it mentions `.` to say that the path is constructed by taking the package name (for example com.foo.bar) and substituting (i.e. replacing) the dots in this package name by `/`: com/foo/bar. That's very different from using `.`and `..` as your answer suggests. BTW, test it with a resource in a jar file. It doesn't work. So, either I'm right, and you can't use them, or you are, and a huge bug exists in the JDK for years without anybody caring.